# getRevokedCertificate(BigInteger) method always returns null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, biginteger, x509

I am trying to check if a certain certificate has been revoked by searching for its entry in a .crl file. For this I am using a simple code, where, on a click of a button .crl file is downloaded, then a serial number of a Certificate is searched in it.

Using [X509CRL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/X509CRL.html).

The problem is, that the method `getRevokedCertificate` **allways returns null**, although I am certain that the the serial number of the revoked certificate is inside the .crl file. I am certain, because the method `crl.getRevokedCertificates().toString()` prints some of the entries, and I am taking the Serial Number from those.

The code below is copy-pastable, made in Android Studio. Needs a only button.

```
public void getCRL(View view) throws  IOException {
    // Force downloading on main thread
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Where is the crl?
    String stURL = "http://www.trustcenter.de/crl/v2/tcclass0.crl";
    URL url = new URL(stURL);

    // Open connection
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        // Get .crtFile
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(in);
        Log.d("All revoked: ", crl.getRevokedCertificates().toString());

        // Test what certificate? Serial number
        String STcertSN = "550B00010002F12E05BFE98E3627";
        BigInteger certSN = new BigInteger(STcertSN,16);
        Log.d("Serial number in decimal: ", certSN.toString());

        // See if revoked
        X509CRLEntry isRevoked = crl.getRevokedCertificate(certSN);

        if (isRevoked != null) {
            Log.d("Revoking: ", isRevoked.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d("Revoing: ","Was not revoked");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("uri","Failed at everything");
    }
    finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
**I have tried the same code now in Eclipse. And the code seems to work okay - I get the message about the found revoked certificate.**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509CRL;
import java.security.cert.X509CRLEntry;

public class crt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        try {
        getCRL();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void getCRL() throws  IOException {
    // Where is the crl?
    String stURL = "http://www.trustcenter.de/crl/v2/tcclass0.crl";
    URL url = new URL(stURL);

    // Open connection
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        // Get .crtFile
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(in);
        System.out.println("All revoked: " + crl.getRevokedCertificates().toString());

        // Test what certificate? Serial number
        String STcertSN = "550B00010002F12E05BFE98E3627";
        BigInteger certSN = new BigInteger(STcertSN,16);
        System.out.println("Serial number in decimal: "+ certSN.toString());

        // See if revoked
        X509CRLEntry isRevoked = crl.getRevokedCertificate(certSN);

        if (isRevoked != null) {
            System.out.println("FOUND REVOKED CERTIFICATE ALARM!: "+ isRevoked.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Revoing: "+"Was not revoked");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("uri" +"Failed at everything");
    }
    finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

If this is a bug in Android, how can I report it?

Comment: And you are not getting any exceptions, right? Have you checked your Logcat?

Comment: No, no exceptions. I am reading my log to get the Serial Number of a revoked certificate and to get the response `Was not revoked`, which is caused by the returned null. Unless I am not catching some and they go unnoticed.

Comment: Are you looking at full logcat or filtered by `d`?

Comment: Checked with `No Filters`. No Exceptions.